# Retrieve records from a specific column with a specific pattern in Oracle database

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g, pattern-matching

The pattern for that specific column should be like below

```
WAP
WAPA
WAPB
or
WAP
AWAP
XWAP
```

or

```
ABC
XABCY
ZABCO
```

so on...

and WAP is not constant that can also vary. I tried like '%A_Z%'; but not working as excepted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve records from a specific column in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704056/retrieve-records-from-a-specific-column-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a pattern of:

- a word
- then a non-word character followed by  word containing that word
- the repeats of that previous pattern

Then you could do something like:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tests( value ) AS
SELECT 'WAP WAPA WAPB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'WAP AWAP XWAP' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC XABCY ZABCO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDE,XABCDE,XXABCDE,ABCDEXXY,XABCDEYY' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Tests
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( value, '^(\w+)(\W\w*\1\w*){2,}$' );
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE                                
--------------------------------------
WAP WAPA WAPB                          
WAP AWAP XWAP                          
ABC XABCY ZABCO                        
ABCDE,XABCDE,XXABCDE,ABCDEXXY,XABCDEYY
```

Comment: it is not a three word, that is just an example. am looking for any characters that form a word and based on that words it should look in that specific column which is related to that word like if ABCDE is a word then that column should be able to retrive records related to that world like ABCDE,XABCDE,XXABCDE,ABCDEXXY,XABCDEYY

Comment: @Pradeep Updated - I've matched the new pattern you've given but your requirements are very unclear. Please edit your question with a detailed description of your expected table values, how you expect the values to be matched and the expected output.

Comment: the output should be like this for a specific word
if the value is something like AABBCC, then results could be
AABBCC
XAABBCC
YAABBCC

i will edit my question once again

Comment: i changed the question to make it clear, can you help out