# Retrieve records from a specific column in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g, pattern-matching

```
S.NO     id        Pid
1        123       PAQ123  
2        433       WSD3FF  
3        565       PAS45E  
4        123       PAQ123X  
5        433       WSD3FFY  
6        123       PAQ123Z
```

suppose the above is the sample records in the database.

Now I want to find out in the database whether there is any word (example PAQ123) which is repeating with some prefixes/suffixes like in (PAQ123X,PAQ123Z).

How can I write a query which would result into the above list scenario?

Comment: `select * from the_table where pid like 'PAQ123%'`?

Comment: PAQ123 should be dynamic. that is just example

Comment: @Pradeep: What do you mean by dynamic? What can be different? How? Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE pid REGEXP_LIKE '^[A-Z]+[0-9]+.*'`

Comment: PAQ123 should be dyamic meaning it can changed with other character and number combination but limited to size between 2 to 10

Comment: Pradeep: If I understand what you are saying, you don't know beforehand the common "word" is PAQ123. Instead, you want the code to identify such "high(er) frequency" words, based on the data in the column. Don't use the term "dynamic" - that has a very different meaning, completely unrelated to your question. For your problem, you will need to make your problem more precise. In principle, you might say "take a 'dictionary' of all letter/digit combinations of length 2 to 10, and count occurrences and see which are most common." That makes sense logically, but is too ambitious/not realistic.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( S_NO, id, Pid ) AS
SELECT 1, 123, 'PAQ123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 433, 'WSD3FF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
SELECT 3, 565, 'PAS45E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 123, 'PAQ123X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 433, 'WSD3FFY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 123, 'PAQ123Z' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM   table_name x
           WHERE  t.id = x.id
           AND    LENGTH( t.Pid ) < LENGTH( x.pid )
           AND    INSTR( x.Pid, t.Pid ) = 1 ) AS num_matches
  FROM   Table_name t
)
WHERE num_matches > 0;
```

**Output**:

```
      S_NO         ID PID     NUM_MATCHES
---------- ---------- ------- -----------
         1        123 PAQ123            2 
         2        433 WSD3FF            1
```

If you want to get the matches then you can use a collection:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT PID
             FROM   table_name x
             WHERE  t.id = x.id
             AND    LENGTH( t.Pid ) < LENGTH( x.pid )
             AND    INSTR( x.Pid, t.Pid ) = 1
           )
           AS stringlist
         ) AS matches
  FROM   Table_name t
)
WHERE matches IS NOT EMPTY;
```

or (since I'm not sure `MULTISET` is in 10g):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CAST(
           ( 
             SELECT COLLECT( PID )
             FROM   table_name x
             WHERE  t.id = x.id
             AND    LENGTH( t.Pid ) < LENGTH( x.pid )
             AND    INSTR( x.Pid, t.Pid ) = 1
           )
           AS stringlist
         ) AS matches
  FROM   Table_name t
)
WHERE matches IS NOT EMPTY;
```

**Output**

```
      S_NO         ID PID     MATCHES 
---------- ---------- ------- ------------------------------------
         1        123 PAQ123  TEST.STRINGLIST('PAQ123X','PAQ123Z')
         2        433 WSD3FF  TEST.STRINGLIST('WSD3FFY')
```